# Display role name on my_account page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, role

I use this code in functions.php to display user role in woocommerce My-Account page (Welcome user...etc.):

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return $user_role;
}
```

But it displays only user role ID, without name. How can this code be modified to display USER ROLE NAME instead?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It returns the translated role name of the current user.

```
function se_get_current_user_role() {
global $wp_roles;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$roles = $current_user->roles;
$role = array_shift( $roles );

return isset( $wp_roles->role_names[ $role ] ) ? translate_user_role( 
$wp_roles->role_names[ $role ] ) : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work anymore. This code is taken from here - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role/